# How to navigate from first.xml to second.xml file with the click of login button which is present in first.xml in android application

Tags: android, android-layout, eclipse-juno

Please help me .I want to navigate from my first page to second with the click of login button  which is designed in first.xml

Comment: check here http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/

Comment: and do some research before asking questions here.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create two activities and launch your other activity by using intents.and the intent must be defined in your manifest

e.g

```
public class Your_first_class extends Activity {
private Button btn;
public TextView txt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buy);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(Your_first_class.this, Your_second_class.class);
             startActivity(myIntent);

        }

    });
```

In your manifest declare it like this

```
<activity android:name=".Your_first_class" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

<activity android:name=".Your_second_class" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

you can also look at this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html for more info on launching other activities with intents

Answer (score 0):

refer this link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/

Move one activity to another activity using Intent.

also refer developer.android.com